# Trying to understand if I need WakeLock

Tags: java, android

Disclaimer: My app already working without any Wake Locks for 1+ year and all is well for *most* devices.

I'm tracking GPS and it works like this:

1. AlarmReceiver starts Service every 5/10/15 minutes (as user wishes)
2. Service subscribes for Location updates and waits MAX 1 minute for good GPS.
3. Wrap up, send data to server and shut down service.

Due to bad connections and bad locations - whole thing take up to 2-3 minutes sometimes. And it works. No matter if phone is sleeping or not.

Now I'm reading about WakeLock and it doesn't make sense to me. How come my stuff is working? Is that coincidence?

Comment: Ah yes, the classic question.  "it works, but... it shouldn't?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come my stuff is working?

A combination of things, including a dollop of luck. :-)

First, as Joel noted, the device wakes up briefly courtesy of your alarm, but the OS is only guaranteed to hold a `WakeLock` for the duration of `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

It is possible that, at least on some versions of Android, requesting GPS updates causes the OS to acquire its own `WakeLock`. This is undocumented behavior AFAIK, and I have never relied upon it personally. If it does, though, and you are doing the rest of your work ("Wrap up, send data to server and shut down service") before removing location updates, that would explain the behavior.

There are still potential gaps in your approach (e.g., if you delegate to a `Service` to do the work and are not holding a `WakeLock` as part of passing control to that service). Statistically speaking, it may fail occasionally but work a lot of the time.

Personally, I recommend using a `WakeLock`, in case the undocumented behavior changes. [That's what I do in `LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll).

Comment: Hmm.. :) Actually I do `removeUpdates` before calling my AsyncTask. But I do subscribe service to AsyncTask updates and completion. There is about 5 HTTP calls to be made, so at least 5+ seconds spent after `removeUpdates` called. Actually, I was hoping you will answer because I looked into switching to your `WakefulIntentService` because it is more what I do..

Comment: @katit: `WakefulIntentService` is not suitable for cases involving work that must last beyond `doWakefulWork()`, such as the asynchronous receipt of a location from `LocationManager`. The "wakeful" properties are good, but the `IntentService` base is not. That is why I wrote `LocationPoller` as an example of the same "wakeful" concept in a different sort of service.

Answer (score 0):

Well reading from the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) documentation..

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing.

Further...

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have
>   your application code run at a specific time, even if your application
>   is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks,
>   timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

So based on that.. I think it makes sense that it currently works; correct me if I'm wrong.